# xinput settings reset in just few seconds

Tags: reset, xinput

I want to make my touchpad natural scroll, so I reversed prop of "Synaptics Scrolling Distance" by add '-'. Like this.

> xinput set-prop 11 275 -112 -112

It works, but in few seconds, the settings reset.
What should I do?

Comment: I have the same issue with a physical mouse. The mouse cursor hangs briefly and then the `xinput` settings are reset.Ubuntu 15.04 (Mate, in my case).

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar. In my case the problem was the mouse disconnecting every few minutes, resetting the configuration. I fixed it by setting up a udev rule by following this answer: [Changes with xinput randomly revert back to default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006660/changes-with-xinput-randomly-revert-back-to-default/1007888#1007888)

Answer (score 0):

My problem seems to be the same, and I think it's actually due to the mouse wire being half-broken.  Knowing this cause may help a lot.  I kept thinking it's software problem LOL