# Changes with xinput randomly revert back to default

Tags: touchscreen, xinput, button, remapping, stylus

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04 (xenial) on a laptop with an ELAN Touchscreen together with a DELL 750-AAHC active stylus. One of the buttons on the stylus behaves as a mouse middle-button, and I want it to be a right button instead.

I can achieve this by doing

```
$ xinput set-button-map "ELAN Touchscreen Pen" 1 3 2
```

(i.e., mapping the function of button 3, which must correspond to the right button, to physical button 2).

This does what I want, but the change is not permanent.

I added the command in `~/.xsessionrc` (according to [the answer on this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492744/how-do-i-automatically-remap-buttons-on-my-mouse-at-startup)), so it's run automatically when I reboot, but the button mapping "randomly" reverts to default on its own: it's working as expected for a while, and suddenly I discover that it doesn't, so I get

```
$ xinput get-button-map "ELAN Touchscreen Pen"
1 2 3 4 5
```

and I have to remap it manually.

I tried a few "suspect" things to see what might be responsible for reverting, but I couldn't figure it out. It's not caused by

- suspending the laptop or turning off the screen
- rotating the screen (this was suspect because xinput is used on rotation to transform the input matrix.)
- toggling touchscreen, touchpad or stylus input on/off (also with xinput).

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**:

I've discovered that this problem is not specific to the stylus: I disabled the finger-touch capability of the screen ("ELAN Touchscreen") earlier for some reason by doing:

```
$ xinput disable "ELAN Touchscreen"
```

and I just discovered that it came back on its own (and the stylus right-click had again reverted). So it seems like all xinput changes revert to default for this unknown reason.

**UPDATE 2**

I found some suspicious entries in `/var/log/syslog` when this happened again. The timestamps were during a time I had not actually been using the laptop for some time, so energy-saving features were probably activated (I have "dim screen" at 9 mins and "switch off" at 10 mins; I will experiment with energy saving and update accordingly).

The pattern bellow is actually repeated many times, with only a few seconds difference between each block.

```
usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 18
usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=2073
usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-8: Product: Touchscreen
usb 1-8: Manufacturer: ELAN
input: ELAN Touchscreen Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:04F3:2073.04EE/input/input7548
input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:04F3:2073.04EE/input/input7549
input: ELAN Touchscreen Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:04F3:2073.04EE/input/input7552
hid-multitouch 0003:04F3:2073.04EE: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
```

In each block, almost everything is the same except a few numbers that increase. Here's the next block for comparison:

```
usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 19
usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=2073
usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-8: Product: Touchscreen
usb 1-8: Manufacturer: ELAN
input: ELAN Touchscreen Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:04F3:2073.04EF/input/input7554
input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:04F3:2073.04EF/input/input7555
input: ELAN Touchscreen Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:04F3:2073.04EF/input/input7558
hid-mul itouch 0003:04F3:2073.04EF: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
```

The device numbers wrap around at 128.

**System**:

- KDE Plasma 5.5.5
- Qt 5.5.1
- Kernel 4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu 64-bit
- xinput version 1.6.2

  XI version on server: 2.3
- X.Org X Server 1.19.5

  Release Date: 2017-10-12

  X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0

Comment: No idea what keeps messing with your xinput but as a workaround, how about putting it in a script and running it every minute through cron? do "crontab -e", scroll to the bottom to add a new line and add: "* * * * * /path/to/script.sh"

Comment: Thanks. I've never dealt with cron, but maybe it's about time. I'll look into it as a possible workaround if all else fails.

Comment: The *xinput* command can be put in the xserver startup configuration file. I am not sure exactly which file it needs to be in because the different X implementations fight each other to which config files have the final say.

Comment: @stumblebee, I guess that's what ~/.xsessionrc does in my case, but as I've mentioned in the post, the change reverts during the session for unknown reasons.

Comment: Add to your update exactly what you did to disable and enable the touchscreen.

Comment: [Here is something](https://askubuntu.com/a/461173/767056) you may want to try to make it persistent.

Comment: It looks this may be due to the stylus powering off after a certain period of inactivity. This would be the equivalent of unplugging the device and plugging it back it.

Comment: @stumblebee, do you mean the stylus or the active digitizer on the screen is powering off? I confirmed it doesn't have to do with the stylus powering off because I removed and re-inserted the battery, and the settings did not revert from that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73311/discussion-between-stumblebee-and-ratler).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug (the fact that the touchscreen device randomly disconnects and reconnects as a new device, which has the side-effect of resetting all settings to default).

As a workaround, you can create your own **udev** rule (file name based on [these suggestions by Daniel Drake](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#files)) that will run a script that re-applies the xinput changes whenever the touchscreen reconnects:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-custom-elan.rules
```

and add this line which contains *"idVendor"* and *"idProduct"* information (from your *syslog*). The **absolute path** to *"elan.sh"* must be used.

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2073", RUN+="/home/username/elan.sh"
```

(which roughly translates to ""when a device that matches the specified attributes is found, run the designated script").

Then create the actual script to run *xinput*:

```
nano /home/username/elan.sh
```

with the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#These lines allow the script to be called by udev rules
export DISPLAY=":0"
export XAUTHORITY="/home/username/.Xauthority"

#Command to remap buttons
xinput set-button-map "ELAN Touchscreen Pen" 1 3 2 4 5
```

And of course make it executable:

```
chmod +x /home/username/elan.sh
```

Without the *export* lines, the script works when called by you (the active user) directly, but it doesn't work when called by udev (the root user). Details can be found in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root/1600#1600) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395027/scripts-launched-from-udev-do-not-have-display-access-anymore/20678530#20678530) answer, but here's a brief summary:

To launch a graphical program on a user's desktop, you need two things: the address (what display the user's desktop is on) and authorisation. When a user logs in, the login manager authorises a connection to the X server by generating a cookie, adding it to the server and passing it to the user by writing it to $HOME/.Xauthority. The root user should, then, be able to connect by knowing the display used by the user and by having access to the Xauthority cookie. This is what the *export* lines achieve.

**Note**: the fact that the display number is hardcoded might cause a problem under some circumstances, but in this usage scenario (single user of a personal laptop) it will probably be OK.

Comment: @Ratler Thanks for the edit and additional information.

Comment: This was almost there, so I added some points (mainly the 'export' statements in the script) to make it the complete solution that (finally!) worked for me. Thanks for your help!