# Cannot permanently disable touch screen Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, xorg, touchscreen, input-devices

Before you mark my answer as a duplicate, please read.

I am facing ghost touch issues with my touchscreen on my Dell laptop. I have read through almost all answers here and on other sites and the issue still persists.

Here were some pointers I got.

**Suggestion 1**: Head over to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
**Situation 1**: No such file. I only have 40-libinput.conf

**Suggestion 2**: In whatever file you have, edit the touchscreen section to add

```
Option "Ignore" "on"
```

**Situation 2**: No effect

**Suggestion 3** : In whatever config file you have turn the match to off.

```
  MatchIsTouchscreen "off"
```

**Situation 3** : No effect. Sometimes it freezes in the login screen and have to reboot the system.

**Suggestion 4** : Find the xinput id of the driver and kill it. Since the id can change anytime, use the name.
**Situation 4** : I am a beginner, I ended up writing this piece of shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput | while read line ;
do
    if [[ $line =~ .*Touchscreen.* ]]
    then
        idString=$(echo $line|cut -d'=' -f 2)
        id="${idString%%[*}"
        id=$(echo "$id" |xargs)
        echo "Going to Disable Touchscreen with Id: $id"

        xinput disable $id
    fi
done
```

*(The above code was tested successfully when one day the ghost touches magically stopped for a day. I re-enabled it and re-tested. Do point out any mistakes if any, but for the love of god, please do not give me a fancy way to do the same thing)*

I was asked to place this in `/etc/X11/xinit` for global effect and in `/home/.config/autorun` for user specific effect. I made the script executable as can be seen,

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root touchscreen_killer.sh*
```

Now although this seems to work, It does not work always. Every now and then I end up facing ghost touches again, and am unable to even go past the login screen. Even if I do, the ghost touches open up a huge number of applications forcing the PC to finally crash.
Hence unable to carry out the silly suggestions like manually finding xinput id and disabling it that I saw in many other answers.

So still I have NOT been able to PERMANENTLY disable my touch screen. It bugs me that it is so easy in Windows. I just disabled the touch screen in Device Manager and windows works fine thereafter. But Ubuntu is is giving me a hard time.

If anyone has any solution that is not mentioned above, please do share. HELP !!

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 hit end-of-life earlier this month. You need to switch to a supported release like 18.04.

Comment: Upgraded to Ubuntu 18 as requested. Issue still exists

Comment: OK. I've [edit]ed the question accordingly, and retracted my close vote.

Comment: I spent ages (weeks) dealing with [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1007888/792020), and though there are many differences, I get the feeling it might help (particularly regarding making your changes stick) if it's not one of the answers you've already read. Sorry I have no time today to look into this in detail, but if it's still a problem when I'm back, I'll do my best to help out.

Comment: @Ratler Interesting post, but I see that it is for the older elan instead of the newer libinput

Comment: Turns out deleting the whole driver section from /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf solved the problem partially. Touch is disabled post login. However touchscreen is still active during login, which I wish to disable and hope for help

Comment: Try this solution? https://mastizada.com/blog/disable-touchscreen-in-gnulinux/